# Workaround to successfully profile python script using scalene profiler on macOS? Just forget it and use machine with Windows or Linux?

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, profiling, scalene

Computational Science SE question [How amenable is this 2D Frenkel–Kontorova-like energy minimization problem in Python to the use of a modest PC + GPU? (Heavy reliance on indexing)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40634/17869) contains a short example script and **note 3** links to my first attempt at profiling using [scalene](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene)

The results were uninformative, so I followed [a recommendation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60144488#60144488) that I try the `--profile-all` option. After running for 30 minutes without finishing on a script that took seconds to run I added a CPU percent limit; what I assume means only things that used at least 2% of the CPU time would be profiled in depth.

```
scalene --html --outfile prof.html  --profile-all --cpu-percent-threshold 2 myscript.py
```

I received a two line error and was exited from python in a normal way.

```
Error getting real path: 2
Scalene error: received signal SIGABRT
```

This issue was closed in scalene [issue #110](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene/issues/110) and there are links there to

- https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene/commit/6636d95d7ea9a16adedaedbd4ff0926374798f2b

> **Q: How do I use Scalene with PyTorch?**
>
> **A:** Scalene works with PyTorch version 1.5.1. **There's a bug** in newer versions of PyTorch (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/57185) that interferes with Scalene (discussion here: https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene/issues/110).

there's more information there as well

and

- Pytorch open issue #57185 [Segmentation fault with ITIMER_REAL](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/57185) PyTorch throws SIGSEGV when running alongside timer on MacOS x86

**Question:** Is there a workaround to successfully profile python script using scalene profiler on macOS? Or should I just move to a machine with Windows or Linux and forget about trying for now?

Answer (score 1):

The message, `Error getting real path: 2`, seems to have to do with scalene finding your script or a path internal to your script possibly.
Ensure you're referencing a full, valid path for `myscript.py`, taking into account which directory you're at in the terminal. You may need to change directory.

The `SIGABRT` message is different from the `SIGSEGV` issue listed, though, if you wanted to test it, you could uninstall PyTorch (`pip uninstall torch`) and reinstall a specific version (`pip install 'torch==1.5.1'`).

Comment: I always first cd to the directory where my script and all necessary data and files are ready and waiting and avoid using paths. But it may be that a full path is required here for some reason, so I'll look into that, thanks! As for torch, I'll give that a try. First I'll learn how to make a new environment so I don't uninstall the most recent torch from my main anaconda installation.Once again very helpful, thanks!  I'll update here again once I try these.